# change variable depend on dropdown selection in StreamBuilder, Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-futurebuilder, stream-builder

I'm currently writting a following code which

1. fetch data and assign it as initial data
2. create dropdown inside of streambuilder
3. when dropdown is changed, change variable
   Now I am aware that this won't work because running setState will rerun streambuilder which rechange value of category1 to userData["category1"].
   What modification would I need to fix this? I would like to solve it in method that not getting value with initstate.

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> categoryList = [
    const DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text("ビューティー"), value: "ビューティー"),
    const DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text("ファッション"), value: "ファッション"),
    const DropdownMenuItem<String>(child: Text("カフェ"), value: "カフェ"),],
String? category1;

StreamBuilder(
  stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user').doc(user.email!).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
    if (snapshot.hasData){SizedBox(
      Map userData = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      category1 = userData["category1"];
      width: 220,
      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        value: category1,
        items: categoryList,
        onChanged: (String? value) {
          setState(value){
            category1 = value;
          }
        },
      )),}
      }
  )
```

Reason why I don't won't to solve it with initstate is because I have exact problem with following question.
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545077/retrieving-firebase-data-in-init-state)
the initstate won't fill a data before widget are made and value return null.

tried to solve it by using initstate but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly try to check if the value of `category1` is null before allocating value to it. So that you make sure only the first time the value is assigned. Like:

```
if(category1 != null){
  category1 = userData["category1"];
}
```